# What is the difference between correlation and cross-correlation?

Tags: time-series, correlation, cross-correlation

Skimming through scientific papers I bumped into both correlation and cross-correlation. How similar or different are these two concepts?

Answer (score 2):

You probably encountered those terms in a time-series context (if not, tell us details of the context!) Then, correlation probably refers to autocorrelation, that is, the correlation of a stationary time series $X_t$ with itself at other times:
$$
  \rho(h)=\text{cor}(X_t,X_{t-h})
$$
(so that $\rho(0)=1$ always). Then crosscorrelation is the correlation between stationary time series $X_t$ and $Y_t$ at same or different lags.
Stationarity means that statistical properties of the series is invariant under time shift, so that specifically means and variances are constant, and autocorrelations do only depend on the time lag $h$, not absolute time $t$.